# Optimal way of presenting some information

Tags: alignment

I want to  present the following information in some way:
[image]

I can achieve this by using an `aligned` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
g(2) &= 4       &\qquad             &G(2) = 4       \\
g(3) &= 9       &\qquad     4 \leq  &G(3) \leq 7    \\
g(4) &= 19      &\qquad             &G(4) = 16      \\
g(5) &= 37      &\qquad     6 \leq  &G(5) \leq 17   \\
g(6) &= 73      &\qquad     9 \leq  &G(6) \leq 24   \\
g(7) &= 143     &\qquad     8 \leq  &G(7) \leq 33   \\
g(8) &= 279     &\qquad    32 \leq  &G(8) \leq 42
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

This works fine, of course, but I am now wondering if there might be some better way of presenting this information. I am open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: The space after the `\leq` in the "second" column can be corrected by following it by an empty group: `\leq {} &`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not knowing what it is supposed to demonstrate, it seems correct, except the left hand `leq` doesn't have a correct spacing, due to the code. So I propose this code, which is also simplified, based on `alignat*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
g(2) &= 4 & G(2) &= 4 \\
g(3) &= 9 & 4 \leq G(3) &\leq 7 \\
g(4) &= 19 & G(4) &= 16 \\
g(5) &= 37 & 6 \leq G(5) &\leq 17 \\
g(6) &= 73 &\ 9 \leq G(6) &\leq 24 \\
g(7) &= 143 & 8 \leq G(7) &\leq 33 \\
g(8) &= 279 & \hspace{3em}32 \leq G(8) &\leq 42
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

What about showing your data on a chart?

[image]

This is done with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
numeric u, v;
u = 2;
v = 8;

vardef showit(expr n, a, b, c) = 
    interim ahangle := 180;
    drawdblarrow (a*u, b*v) -- (a*u, c*v);
    z[n] = (a * u, (b+c) * 1/2 v);
    fill fullcircle scaled 10 shifted z[n] withcolor 7/8[blue, white];
    draw fullcircle scaled 10 shifted z[n];
    label(decimal n, z[n]);
enddef;

path xx, yy;
xx = 8 left -- 290u * right;
yy = 8 down -- 44v * up;

beginfig(1);

for G=8 step 8 until 40:
    draw xx shifted (0, G*v) withcolor 7/8;
    label(decimal G, (-10, G*v));
endfor
for g=40 step 40 until 280:
    draw yy shifted (g*u, 0) withcolor 7/8;
    label(decimal g, (g*u, -10));
endfor

showit(2, 4, 4, 4);
showit(3, 9, 4, 7);
showit(4, 19, 16, 16);
showit(5, 37, 6, 17);
showit(6, 73, 9, 24);
showit(7, 143, 8, 33);
showit(8, 279, 32, 42);

drawarrow xx; label.rt("$g$", point 1 of xx);
drawarrow yy; label.top("$G$", point 1 of yy);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```